# Windows Network List Manager API returns incorrect connectivity information

Tags: windows, winapi, active-directory, connectivity

The API is returning the network type as "public" when it is in fact connected to the AD.

### Background

I have a credential provider that at user logon, uses [`INetworkListManager::GetNetworks`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/netlistmgr/nf-netlistmgr-inetworklistmanager-getnetworks) to enumerate all networks on a client and uses [`INetwork::GetCategory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/netlistmgr/nf-netlistmgr-inetwork-getcategory) and [`INetwork::GetDomainType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/netlistmgr/nf-netlistmgr-inetwork-getdomaintype) to determine whether the client is connected to AD. If yes, it'll proceed to use the [`IADsUser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iads/nn-iads-iadsuser) interface to query the AD for the user's groups. The AD connectivity check is necessary because if there was no AD connection, the query groups operation would stall for many seconds before failing, and this adversely impacts user experience. The following problem appeared after upgrading from Window 7 to 10.

### Problem

Frequently, `GetCategory` returns [`NLM_NETWORK_CATEGORY_PUBLIC`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/netlistmgr/ne-netlistmgr-nlm_network_category) and `GetDomainType` returns [`NLM_DOMAIN_TYPE_NON_DOMAIN_NETWORK`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/netlistmgr/ne-netlistmgr-nlm_domain_type) both before **and after** a successful AD query for the user's groups. The values should have been `NLM_NETWORK_CATEGORY_DOMAIN_AUTHENTICATED` and `NLM_DOMAIN_TYPE_DOMAIN_AUTHENTICATED`. After logon, Network and Sharing Center shows that user is connected to domain network. This means `GetCategory` and `GetDomainType` can no longer be counted on to reliably return network connectivity information. What could be causing this problem?

Alternatively, are there other ways to resolve the problem of query groups operation stalling when there is no AD connection?

Edit: some new findings. The problem frequently occurs immediately after boot, and goes away if we:

- wait for ~5 minutes before logging in.
- unplug, then plugin in the network cable, then wait ~30 seconds before logging in.

Comment: Did the method `INetwork::GetCategory()` and `INetwork::GetDomainType()` succeed and return `S_OK`?

Comment: @DrakeWu-MSFT Yes I made sure to check the return status of both functions are S_OK before using the returned values.

Comment: Try to detect whether to connect to the AD domain by getting the return value of the domain controller of [`IADsADSystemInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iads/nn-iads-iadsadsysteminfo), Or indirectly by getting the current domain name through [`DsRoleGetPrimaryDomainInformation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dsrole/nf-dsrole-dsrolegetprimarydomaininformation)

Comment: @DrakeWu-MSFT No luck with both functions. `DsRoleGetPrimaryDomainInformation` is able to return the domain name even when network is disconnected and `IADsADSystemInfo` stalls randomly just like the `IADsUser` interface (albeit a bit shorter - 15s vs 45s) when there is network connectivity but no domain connectivity.